Dart List error The class 'List' doesn't have an unnamed constructor
I'm trying to create a List of servers in this way:
class Server {
  final String country;
  final String ip;
  final String username;
  final String password;

  const Server(
      {required this.country, required this.ip, required this.username, required this.password});

  static List<Server> allServers() {
    var myServers = new List<Server>();

    myServers.add(const Server(
        country: "Italy"
        ip: "1.2.3.4.example.com",
        username: "user1",
        password: "password1"
    ));
    myServers.add(const Server(
        country: "United States",
        ip: "5.6.7.8.example.com",
        username: "user2",
        password: "password2"
    ));
    return myServers;
  }
}

I get the error "The class 'List' doesn't have an unnamed constructor"
How can I fix it?
Thanks in advance

Your code is almost right but you have followed the wrong syntax.
Please refer below example. I have just redraft your example

void main() {
  final a = Server.allServers();
  print(a);
}

class Server {
  final String country;
  final String ip;
  final String username;
  final String password;

  const Server({
    required this.country,
    required this.ip,
    required this.username,
    required this.password,
  });

  static List<Server> allServers() {
    /// Here is your mistake
    var myServers = <Server>[];

    myServers.add(const Server(
        country: "Italy",
        ip: "1.2.3.4.example.com",
        username: "user1",
        password: "password1"));
    myServers.add(const Server(
        country: "United States",
        ip: "5.6.7.8.example.com",
        username: "user2",
        password: "password2"));
    return myServers;
  }
}


